# Android AlertDialog input number value to be passed to progress dialog async task thread running

Tags: android

On the click of OK Button I have to collect the number entered in the EditText
and pass the same to AsyncTask.
Create AsyncTask - AsyncTask must start & execute for x secs(x is the number passed from the click on OK Button) which is passed as the argument to the AsyncTask, with the ProgressDialog being display to the user during the AsyncTask execution.

Can you please help me with this??

Comment: what you tried so far? show your code

Comment: use `CountDownTimer` inside `doInBackground` method and `publishProgress` in `onTick` method

Comment: I am new to android development and sorry if its a basic question. I dont know what I have to code in doBackground. So I asked members of this site. I have searched all forums and google.

Comment: @Anup thanks..till now i used  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {int i = 10;
            while (running) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
 if (i-- == 0) {
                    running = false;
                }
 /*If you want to view the progress in steps of i use publishProgress(i);*/ } return null; But instead of i value, I have to pass x value of EditText in it. I am not getting how to do that.Il try to use method mentioned by u.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the constructor and can pass values to the asynctask using this constructor.

```
 private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     public MyAsyncTask(int count) {
     super();
      // do stuff
    }

    // doInBackground()
}
```

Call the asynctask like this:

```
new MyAsyncTask(5).execute();
```